# Execve invoking

Tags: c, shell, exec

I want to invoke a shell in C program by execve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

main()
{
        char* path = "/bin/sh";
        int err = execve(path, &path, NULL);
        printf("%d\n", err);
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        printf("%x, %x\n", path, &path);
}
```

However the output is:

```
-1
Bad address
80485c0, bf816f4c
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you aren't sending a NULL terminated list of arguments.
You need:

```
char* path[2];
path[0] = "/bin/sh";
path[1] = NULL;
int err = execve(path[0], path, NULL);
```

Answer (score 5):

The second argument to `execve` is defined as being a NULL-terminated list of strings, so you can't simply pass the address of `path`.  It expects an array like this, with the final entry being NULL:

```
arg[0] = "/bin/ls"
arg[1] = "-l"
arg[2] = "/usr/include/std*"
arg[3] = NULL
```

The reason it was failing with a bad pointer is that `execve` would have been looking at each word following `path` to find the arguments, and treating each word as a pointer until it got to the first 0 word.  Since `path` was alone on the stack, it would have been trying to interpret whatever garbage happened to be in memory after the stack beyond `path` as a string pointer.

The solution is simple: you need to construct an array of parameters and add a NULL terminator (since it is of variable length).  The fixed example is below (with a few warnings taken care of):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* path[] = { "/bin/sh", NULL };

    int err = execve(path[0], path, NULL);

    printf("%d\n", err);
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    printf("%p, %p\n", path, &path);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
execl(path, path, NULL)
```

The exec family of functions will automatically execute a shell if the program is a script rather than a process image file.  So you might be able to replace "path" with the pathname of the script.